# Backbonejs - use nested object as id attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-objects

Is it possible to use a nested object as the id attribute in Backbone?

For e.g. something like,

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            'info': {
                'name': ""
            },
        },
        idAttribute: "info.name"
}
```

BTW, the above doesn't work as an ID, I added it here just to give an idea of what I was trying to achieve.

TIA

Comment: you cannot use a nested object as an idattribute

Comment: If you have something mutable (such as an `{info: { ... } }` object) in your `defaults`, use a `defaults` function instead of an object literal. The `defaults` are shallow copied so you're going to end up changing the prototype's `defaults` and wonder why all your models have changed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can directly assign a nested object as an `idAttribute` .

But you can directly set the id on the model when the response is served by the server in the `parse` method

```
parse: function(response) {
   response.id = response.info.name;
   return response;
}
```

Comment: Just a note that not supporting nested idAttributes is by design and will not change: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/pull/598

Comment: This won't always work as you expect, because models are not parsed before they are set on the collection. Calling `collection.fetch({ remove: false })` will therefore result in duplicate models. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tT2D9/3/).

Answer (score 0):

as @Sushanth says, `parse` is for sure a good way to do this.

But generally using nested objects within Backbone Models is unsafe and not the best way to do it. When you change your `response.info.name` property, and you bind events to `response.info`, you will not get notified.

After a few years with Backbone, I would like to tell you, that parsing your received models from server into primitive objects is the best you can do.

If you want your models to go back to server exactly the same way they came in, you could override the toJSON function, which could transform it back. Of course, you need to implement those two... :/